# mailto uri - javascript window.open and then close, still stays open in < IE8

Tags: javascript, location, uri, document, mailto

```
function SendInfo(href) {
    var subject= "Some information";
    var body = "I thought you might find this information interesting:\r\n\r\n<";
    body += document.location;
    body += ">";
    var uri = "mailto:?subject=";
    uri += encodeURIComponent(subject);
    uri += "&body=";
    uri += encodeURIComponent(body);
    win = window.open(uri);
    win.close();
}
```

In FF, Chrome and IE9, the new tab/window closes as it should.

However in IE8 and below, a new window opens and the user gets a security warning.

Is there a better way to approach this to prevent those issues?

jsbin: http://jsbin.com/itazab

Comment: put this `win.open("", "_self", "");` in-front of this `win.close();`

Comment: I also did some digging, and found that this can occur when developing locally versus once it's published (different zones and such)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not optimal to open a window that you need to close.
If you did not get a warning you could use setTimeout like this:

```
win = window.open(uri);
setTimeout(function() { win.close();},1000);
```

Instead I suggest you do this

```
function SendInfo(href) {
  var subject= "Some information";
  var body = "I thought you might find this information interesting:\r\n\r\n<";
  body += href; // or document.location;
  body += ">";
  var uri = "mailto:?subject=";
  uri += encodeURIComponent(subject);
  uri += "&body=";
  uri += encodeURIComponent(body);
  return uri;
}

<a href="#" onclick="this.href=SendInfo(location.href)">Tell a friend</a>
```

Comment: Those changes actually did not return anything - Outlook didn't open and it didn't throw any errors

Comment: try `onmousedown` instead of `onclick`